# plot a data file as a contour plot in a specific region

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, contour

I have a set of [data](https://ufile.io/u01po) and want to be plotted in a specific region. I draw the region using tikz and when I want to add the data as a contour plot in the region, I don't get the results. How can I Plot the data file in a specific region? Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\val{0}

\foreach \a in {0, 1,...,60}
\draw[Azure4] (\a:9.7) -- (\a:10);

\foreach \a in {0, 10,...,60}
\draw[Azure4] (\a:0) -- (\a:10);    

\foreach \r in {0, 2, ...,10}
\draw [Azure4] (\r,0) arc (0:60:\r);

\draw [black, ultra thick]  (0,0) -- (10,0) arc (0:60:10) -- (0,0);

\draw (0: 10.6) node {$0$};

\draw (30: 10.6) node {$\frac{\pi}{6}$};
\draw (60: 10.6) node {$\frac{\pi}{3}$};

\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=9,
labels=false},thick] {data.dat};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot3` can be only invoked inside an `axis` environment.

Comment: Please give me the solution by correcting my code and obtaining an output.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Your data is not in the matrix form required to do the plot, see e.g. p. 152 of the pgfplots manual v1.16. In addition you are missing a table, that is, once you have brought your data in matrix form by adding empty lines you can try `\begin{axis}
\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=9,
labels=false},thick] table[header=false] {data.dat};
\end{axis}`.

Comment: If I use `axis`, the output is not placed in the region I had plotted before.

Comment: You will make it much easier for others to help you if you (1) format your data file to be in the right format and (2) include it via `\begin{filecontents}{data.dat} <data> \end{filecontents}`.